# Define once an event listener for multiple widgets

Tags: android

Given *N* widgets of the same 'kind' (intentionally avoiding the *class* or *type* terms here for avoiding confusion), I'd like to assign the same event listener to all of them in an idiomatic way.

For clarity, it'd be something akin to `$(".foo").click(...);` in jQuery. Notice the class selector.

Right now I can code it in a fairly concise way, but I was wondering whether there is an specific mechanism in Android for achieving this.

**Update** - example:

```
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ...
    buttonN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonN);

    buttons = new Button[]{button1, button2, ..., buttonN};

    // Pretty imperative.
    // Would't it be better to specify that all buttons belong to the same 'kind',
    // and set a listener to that 'kind'?
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(...);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question more as its little bit confusing

Comment: Can you try to explain it using a java/android comparison?

Comment: Is your question about how to assign the same listener to multiple objects or how to assign a listener to multiple objects in one line of code?

Comment: I don't mind about the lines of code it takes - I just want to do it the best way.